# Where is the virtual function table for C++ class stored?

Tags: c++

I tried to find where exactly virtual function table gets stored for c++ class.
i found some answers like its a "static array of function pointers"
so will it get stored in data segment read only memory? (initialised one)

Comment: It's implementation defined. The standard doesn't even require there to be any vtable _at all_, compilers could implement virtual inheritance in other ways if they found that to be feasible.

Comment: Why is it an interesting question? How would you use the answer?

Answer (score 2):

Most probably yes. However, it's not mandated. It's not even mandated that polymorphism is implemented via virtual function table, but on most platforms it is. These are implementation details, as long as a compiler obeys the behavior set by the standard, it can do whatever it wants.

A `vftable` is one per class and stored in only one place in memory.

Comment: what are the other ways by which compiler could use to achieve run time polymorphism?

Comment: @saumitra not efficient, but each instance `could` have a collection of pointers to methods.

Comment: "Only one place in memory" is common but certainly not universal. With DLLs, you can end up with multiple copies. Hopefully identical, but ODR violations and their Undefined Behavior can badly break this.

Comment: @MSalters I don't see how, if the dll's are properly loaded. I think you'd get link errors if multiple dll's contain the same vftable.

Comment: @Luchian Grigore: vtables don't need to appear in export tables. Essentially, a `new Foo` in A.DLL will use the vtable from A.DLL, whereas a `new Foo` in B.DLL will use the vtable from B.DLL. If you followed the One Definition Rule, this is not a problem. (Exception: when pointers to member functions are compared, the compiler has to ensure identity, which _might_ involve exporting them - but a PTMF can also be implemented as "3rd vtable member" which doesn't cause a need to export the vtable).

Answer (score 1):

When you make any function virtual, the compiler will insert a vptr inside your class. As a result, the size of the class will grow by 4 bytes (on Win32).This pointer holds the address of the virtual table (vtable). vtable is constructed by the compiler at compile time and is basically nothing but an array of function pointers. The function pointers are actually pointers to the virtual functions of that particular class. To be more exact, the virtual table is a static array of function pointers, so that different instances of the same class can share that vtable. Since, static members are stored in the data section (.data), the vtable is also stored in the data section of the executable.

Answer (score 0):

It's implementation dependent, yes.

And for g++ (4.9.0), virtual table (not the pointer) is stored in the section .rodata of ELF file and its corresponding segment LOAD in memory.