# If a class has a parent class(Inherited) how does the VFTables get stored in the objects memory?

Tags: c++, memory

First of all I would like to start by saying I've read this post
[Where is the virtual function table for C++ class stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10387691/where-is-the-virtual-function-table-for-c-class-stored)

It kind of confirmed what I did know about VFTables. They are stored in the first index of a class objects memory at Obj + 0x0

In the objects I have assessed though they do not contain the vftables of the parent class.

So my question is, am I looking in the wrong place? Does only the main class have it's VFTable stored in the object?

There is so many more questions I'd like to ask but I'm hoping one good answer on this subject should answer any possible questions

Comment: A vtable (as it's commonly called) can store pointers to the *parents* functions, if the class doesn't override them. For a specific implementation you have to look at a specific compiler.

Comment: vtables are stored as static data and objects with virtual functions etc. have a pointer to the respective vtable. See: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HClSfuT2bFA&ab_channel=Creel

Comment: A derived class can start with vtable looking just like its parent's, and can then replace the functions  it is overriding plus add any new virtual functions at the end of the table.